# Differentiability of a function on $R^2$ and $C$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Can a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ that is differentiable  not be holomorphic-analytic?.

Comment: Have you heard of the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: Yes of course. I know that to be analytic must satisfy C.R eq and  the parts of f must be tota differentiable.

Comment: Great, so being analytic/holomorphic is the same as satisfying C-R and being a differentiable map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore can you find a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself that is differentiable but does not satisfy C-R?

Comment: nope .I cant think atm .Im a bit tired.could you give me an example?Im confused as to why  differentiability  on $R^2$ does not mean differentiability on C since C isomorphic to $R^2$

Comment: We have the idea of complex multiplication, which changes how we approach points in $\mathbb{C}$ compared to $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the map $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by 
$$f(x,y) := (u(x,y),v(x,y)) = (x,0).$$
This is differentiable since it's a polynomial. However it does not satisfy the C-R equations because for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$\frac{du}{dx} = 1 \neq 0 = \frac{dv}{dy}.$$ 
It therefore is not analytic when considered as a map from the complex plane to itself.

Answer (score 1):

Holomorphic maps of $\mathbb{C}$ with nonzero derivative are conformal. So all you need is a differentiable map of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that does not preserve angles infinitesimally. For example, $f(x,y)=(2x,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x,y)=(x, -y)$ which is equivalent to $f(z)=\bar{z}$ is differentiable, but not analytic

Comment: $f(z)=\overline{z}$ corresponds to $(x,y)\mapsto(x,-y)$.